# trouble connecting to mysql container from different computer on same network as container host

Tags: mysql, docker

I set up a mysql container on a server, and I can connect to the mysql database from the host machine but not from another computer on the same network as the server. Although, I can ssh into the server. Please help.

Here is my Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my-db-name
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

To connect from the host I use command:

```bash
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3306
```

To connect from another computer on network I tried these two command:

```bash
mysql -u root -p -h server-name --port 3306
mysql -u root -p -h server-ip-address --port 3306
```

I can ping server-name and ping server-ip-address and those reply but I can't connect to the database.

Comment: you must still allow the firewall to let the packages pass

Comment: Thanks this was the issue. I thought all the ports were open, but when I ran `docker run --publish 3600:80 nginx` and went to server:3600 nothing showed up. I switched to an open port and everything worked.